# Font Awesome + Electron

Tags: angular, path, font-awesome, electron

I have an application made angular2, electron where I'm trying to insert fonts awesome.
When I compile the application for the web it works, when I compile for the desktop it misses the font path.
In more detail the application is structured in this way:

```
├─src/
├─build/
   ├─index.html
   ├─app/
   ├─fonts/
   |  ├─fonts...
   ├─font-awesome.min.css
```

I run the same project in the same folder `build` for desktop with `electron build/`.
This is what I set in my index.html.

**index.html**

```
<base href="./">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css">
```

This is the wrong path:

```
/C:/wamp/www/JUICE/projects/lightRoom/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3:1
```

This is the right path:

```
/C:/wamp/www/JUICE/projects/lightRoom/build/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3:1
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved, I moved the font-awesome.min.css in /css folder.